# Does hibernate envers imply one transaction at a time?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, hibernate-envers

As I understand from documentations, *hibernate envers* revisions are global, so I think that with every transaction in the system, this revision number must increment by one, but is this imply some locking on revision number that prevents concurrency in transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how the revision ids are generated. If the generator (e.g. a sequence in Postgres, or `auto_increment` in MySQL) allows for concurrent generation, concurrent transactions should also work.

Just as with normal entities, you can usually do two inserts to a table at the same time.